# What is the term for an error where a space is missing?

Tags: language-agnostic

What is the name of/term for a coding error where you forgot a space?
Example

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM      public.employees 
    INNERJOIN public.departments ON employees.dept_id = departments.id
```

Notice the INNERJOIN should be INNER JOIN.

Comment: I call it a _"typo"_

Comment: @TedLyngmo I don't disagree, but I have seen a proper name for this typo and having it would help for a peer review I am doing.

Comment: Whoever is reading this peer review is not going to think better of you for making them google a definition, when you could have just said "missing space".

Answer (score 1):

[Syntax error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_error).

Most programming languages or formal grammars have a very specific and deterministic syntax that must be meet before other phases of checking occur such as semantics and type checking.

---

While a syntax error can be thought of as a class of error and you are seeking something more specific, in my 30 years of coding and writing parsers and such the only way to make this more specific is to give the line number and column position of where the space was expected and the production rule(s) being evaluated at the time can help identify what was expected.